# When and why do vanishing cycles of Lefschetz fibrations exist?

Tags: fibration

On page 6 of the article [Symplectic Lefschetz fibrations with arbitrary fundamental groups](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9810042), the authors state that for a Lefschetz fibration (with total space of dimension 4) the retraction of the regular fibre onto a critical fibre contains a vanishing cycle.

- Why does such a vanishing cycle exist?
- Is existence of vanishing cycles guaranteed when the total space has dimension higher than 4?

Answer (score 1):

Vanishing cycles always exist iff you have at least one critical point $x$ in your Lefschetz fibration f ; in this case there are Complex charts $(w,z)$ with $f(w,z)= w^2+z^2$ . Now, this map has a critical value at $w^2+ z^2 =0 $ You get this critical
value by collapsing maps $w^2+z^2= \epsilon$ ; $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$